# MongoDB fetching slow

Tags: c#, mongodb, indexing, database-performance, bigdata

I have a requirement to run the following query and get the results in as close to milliseconds as possible. The following query returns 200,000 records (4 columns each with a 5 digit value).

Tried the following query on RoboMongo:

```
db.MarketData.find(
   {
     $or: [ { Symbol: "X" }, { Symbol: "Y" }, { Symbol: "Z" },{ Symbol: "A" }]
   }
).sort({ColumnB:-1});
```

The query time says 0.001 seconds to execute on Robomongo. Looks like it fetches few results at a time. However when I run the query on C#, it takes close to 3 seconds. Everything is running on a single machine hence there could be no networking impact etc. Is there anything I can do to bring response times down further? E.g. any buffer settings etc. or anything you can think of?

C# Code:

```
public static async void ProcessDataAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);

    var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("MarketData");
    var builder = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter;
    var filter = builder.Eq("Symbol", "X") | builder.Eq("Symbol", "Y") | builder.Eq("Symbol", "Z") | builder.Eq("Symbol", "A");
    var sort = Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("ColumnB");
    var task = collection.Find(filter).Sort(sort).ToListAsync();

    var x = await task;

    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
}
```

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the returned data in the end? ToListAsync fetches the entire result set to an in memory list before returning which is probably the cause of the delay.

Comment: @joachimisaksson.. I go through the records and run a 100ms process which then gives a result. This is a financial stock market based application and hence would need to complete the said execution within few milliseconds in total.

Comment: Make sure you have index on Symbol and ColumnB. I believe Robomongo fetch 50 records by default so if you bench mark is robomongo, try limiting your result set to 50 too in your C# code.

Answer (score 0):

From your query,What I can suggest is use $in over $or.

you can refer why here[$orvs$in](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#_S_or%22)

finally query will look like below:

```
db.collection_name.find({Symbol:{$in:[X,Y,Z,A]}})
```

prefer using [skip](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/) to get more optimization.